# How to store datepicker for jquery into database

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, eclipse, datepicker

For my datepicker, I am able to display it on eclipse and it works fine visually, however, after selecting the date, I am unable to store it anywhere. This is my current code for my datepicker.

```
$(function() { 
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst){ 
          $("input[name='date']").val(dateText);}
    });
  } );
```

I am unable to store it either locally or into my database, or even alert it. I have received errors such as [object Object] and [object htmlinputelement].

I would really appreciate if someone can give me a step-by-step on how I can store the value of the datepicker.

The reference for my datepicker is: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
& I'm developing it on eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AJAX`. Assuming you have a form, that form has an input for the date and an `id` on that input like `date` let's say:

```js
var date = $('#date').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'your_script.php', 
    data: {date: date},
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
})
```

Also you need a serverside script.

**UPDATE**:

I've made you a fiddle to see alerting the date after selecting it. I've created an HTML form with an input for the datepicker. [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/cgf30q0u/1/).

A simple example to store the value from the datepicker is to save it for example in local storage, in your browser more exactly, using, as you have seen in the fiddle JavaScript's `localStorage`.

Comment: Hi! I really appreciate your reply. I'm really sorry to say I'm not advanced enough to have a good understanding on how AJAX works so I'm not sure I can do that. Would there be a simpler but efficient method?

Comment: @03131992, ok. I've updated my answer with a link to a jsfiddle. Check that simple example. You can build from that. But if you want to store it to a database you need to know a serverside language like `PHP`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a php for this already, but I just wanna know, should I be initialising the datepicker?

Comment: What do you mean? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to store the datepicker so that if the user has booked an appointment, they will be able to select the date on the datepicker. I read somewhere that upon using datepicker for the first time, it should be initialised, & I'm not sure how to go about that. I apologise if I was unclear. Also, since I'm using eclipse, I am unable to do the html form action method= post, is there an alternative way? Once again, thank you

Comment: You already are initialising it when you do `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({})'`. When you say you want to store the datepicker I suppose you mean the datepicker chosen value,. You can use either PHP or a more elegant solution like I suggested in the first place, AJAX.

Comment: Thank you for informing me of that. Is there any other way I could post the form? I'm not sure I can use the form action method=post on eclipse!

Comment: I'm not sure about that, as I've never used `Eclipse`, but maybe you can use another IDE, like `notepad++`.

Comment: Hello! It worked already, thank you so much! I am really extremely grateful. Thank you!

Comment: Ok. I'm glad. Make sure to accept the answer if you think it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using an ID to initialize datepicker, I'll assume there's only one instance of datepicker whose value you want.

You can just use `val()`

```
var datetime = $("#datepicker").val()
```

or

```
var datetime = document.getElementById("datepicker").value
```

Comment: Hi! I have done this before but it gave me an "undefined" error. I wasn't sure how to proceed after that!